# Colormaps in Bokeh

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, bokeh

I have some problems with color palette on matplotlib.

I want to show only 2 colors on legend because I'm showing a dummy variable (0 and 1).
Code works well with 0 and 1 values (red and blue). The problem is legend (see image).[image]

```
palette = brewer['RdBu'][8]
```

If I put 2 (only 2 colors) on the previous code, I receive an error, because the palette contains 8 colors.

How can I change it?

```
palette = brewer['RdBu'][8]

palette = palette[::-1]

color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette = palette, low = 0, high = 1)

tick_labels = {'0': '0', '1': '1'}

color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper, label_standoff=8,width = 500, height = 20,
border_line_color=None,location = (0,0), orientation = 'horizontal', major_label_overrides = tick_labels)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what is `brewer`? that's not a matplotlib command. Is it from `bokeh`? You might want to add a tag for that too. Make sure to include all your module imports in the question, as that helps people to provide better quality answers.

Comment: Is a bokeh features with matplotlib (i'm sorry).
From website: 
Palette groups included from ColorBrewer. This dictionary is indexed with a palette name to obtain a complete group of palettes, e.g. YlGnBu, and then further indexed with an integer to select a palette of a specific size from the group:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce your palette by slicing:
For example

```
palette = brewer['RdBu'][8][:2]
```

is only two elements long and takes the first and the second item.
The pallete below

```
palette = brewer['RdBu'][8][::7]
```

is also two elements long and takes the first and the last element (it is only a possible way of selecting these two elements).

Comment: Thank you! 

Now, how can I modify legend? I want to read only 0 and 1, not 0.2, 0.4, ecc.

I used this:

```tick_labels={'0':'  Paesi in via di sviluppo ','1':'Paesi sviluppati',"0.2":"","0.4":"","0.8":"","0.60":""}
```

but now I read only 0, 0.6 and 1

Comment: You can add `ticker=BasicTicker(desired_num_ticks=2)` to your `ColorBar`. This comes from `bokeh.models`.